# How can I remove all properties in Jmeter after the run?

Tags: properties, jmeter, removeall, jsr

I usually set properties within the run in Jmeter. How can remove all these properties after the run without knowing their names?

I usually use `props.remove()` to remove only one specific property, but how can remove all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties lifetime is limited by the JVM lifetime so it's enough to restart JMeter to remove any custom properties.

Use [`props.clear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#clear--) function in any of the [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) (the syntax assumes [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black))

Demo:

[image]

However if you want to keep original JMeter properties for whatever reason:

[image]

You can store them into and interim object (or to the file) somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) and restore it in the [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group)